# StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogger. MavenEJBModule in an EAR

Tags: maven, ejb, log4j2

I am fairly new to java and classpaths..

I have an EJB project which has a dependency on log4j2 in it's POM. It runs within an EAR and therefore is an EJBModule within the EAR POM. I also have a parent POM which both the EAR and the EJB project derive from. I am getting the error "StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogger" when attempting to retrieve the logger using the LogManager. My log4j2.xml file sits in the  src/main/resources folder of the EJB Project.

I have tried putting the log4j2.xml in the root of the project, and in the EAR. I have tried putting the log4j2 core and api dependecies in the EAR and in the parent POM. I have tried changing the manifest.mf file to include log4j. But none of these things have worked.

I also noticed that the "java.class.path" returns jboss-modules.jar. What does this mean? In my War modules this is different.

I need to know how I can use Maven to provide the log4j jars to the EJBmodule.

Thanks,
Jen

Answer (score 0):

Someone else recently raised a similar issue on the log4j-user [mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/201411.mbox/%3CCABLGb9wky511SWd63t6-D-E3FmhYy5ZBJ_yxa6Hycu-JY2_JQg%40mail.gmail.com%3E). I believe it was eventually tracked down to a JBoss issue. AFAIK, this is not resolved yet. Raising this issue to the JBoss team may speed up resolution.